# Jmeter: login recorded script not working: getting error javascript not enabled

Tags: javascript, performance, jmeter, cookiemanager

login in issue: On running jmeter script recorded through workbench scriptrecorder, getting an error java script is not enabled, not able to complete test. tried to disable cookie manager still login is not working. getting message page got refreshed before navigating to next page. getting login screen only under listener view results tree view.

steps that i did: created test plan, added thread gp, added config element cache manage, cookie manager, HTTP default then added recording controller
recorded script via workbench recording controller.

tried same script via transactional controller and blazemeter recorder.
All scripts are failing at same point. login is not happening so not moving any further.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Can you please post the error message and HTTP request details? JMeter is not a browser, it will not handle javascript.

Comment: seems like error was due to session Id, that was getting changed each time, so need to replace the value with dynamic variable. added more info below about that. if u can let me know how to fix that. Thanks!

Comment: Please use this regular expression `\(sessionToken\":\"\)(.+?)\(\",\"url_domain_sv_SE\)` and the template `$1$`

Comment: Thanks now I'm able to fetch the session Id value. but still script is failing. I can see user is getting logged in, but again its not moving any further, there are couple of get calls are there in my script when user loads. under listener I do not see any error nothing is happening basically I tried with different options like continue if some error or stops. neither it stops nor showing any error.

Comment: I cannot help unless you post your test plan details and view results tree snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Record and replay will not work in the majority of cases, modern web applications are quite complex and they use dynamic parameters for different reasons, i.e. for [page-level state management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) or [security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention). So if you record this parameter and will try to re-use it while replaying it will not work.

The process of handling dynamic parameters in JMeter is known as **correlation** and looks like:

1. Record your scenario 2 times
2. Compare 2 scripts to identify any dynamic values (don't forget to look not only into HTTP Request parameters, but inspect request headers as well, it can be done using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener)
3. Once you identify the dynamic parameters you will need to extract them from previous response, convert them info JMeter Variables and add them to the next request. You can consider using the following test elements for extracting the dynamic values from the responses:

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - when response is text-based
   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) - when response is HTML
   - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - when response is XML, XHTML or HTML
   - [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) - when response is JSON
4. Validate variables values using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and run the whole test to ensure that it is doing what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, yes you are right.
I was trying to record and play from couple of days and didn't think about session variable.

Comment: now I'm stuck in another problem, I'm trying to change the session variable using regular expression extractor, but its not taking the value of the session variable. My regular expression extractor values are: Response Message Ref name: SessionID Reg Exp: (sessionToken":")(.?+)(","url_domain_sv_SE) Template: $2$

I'm sending the parameter value as ${SessionID} its taking sessionID directly as in response ssionToken%3D%2524%257BSessionID%257D%26 and not replacing with its value that I'm trying to send via regular expression.
Can you please let me know where I'm making mistake?

Comment: I am not able to help without seeing at least partial response. In the meantime you can validate your regular expression against live response using RegExp Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. You can also consider using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) to see all JMeter Variables either pre-defined or generated.

Comment: Regular expression is resolved, but still even after logging in, its not moving any further, nor any error. there are couple of Get calls are there in the script, still its not doin any thing. any help ir suggestion. what could be the possible reason here. here is the sampler response:

Comment: Response code: 302
Response message: Moved Temporarily
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: /signin/modules/dashboard/templates/dashboard.jsp
Server: BigIP
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 17 May 2017 03:57:30 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: MRHSession=deleted; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: F5_ST=deleted; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT